# Should I delete the existing replica when create a new replica with the same name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, replication

I have successfully create a replica between 2 geodatabase and use a scheduler to synchronize the replica between the 2 geodatabase several months ago. But the scheduler didn't work because of changes in the original geodb. In this case I need to create the replica once again (according to user's request), my question is if I use the same replica name, is there a need of deleting the existing one? What will happen if I create the replica directly? Any potential dangers? Since this is a in operation system, I cannot afford of failure.

EDIT: After my research from internet, I even cannot find a way to delete a replica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about a two-way replica?

Go into ArcCatalog and right click on the database. Go to Distributed Geodatabases and [Manage Replicas](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_replica_management/003n000000w8000000/). You can right click on the replica name and remove it.

As far as changes to the original database. Depending on what you mean, you can use the [Export Replica Schema tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000001n000000) on the original database and them import that XML into the other database using the [Import Replica Schema tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Import_Replica_Schema/00170000001q000000/), and it should add the changes to your database.

I'd highly suggest reading this documentation on [Schema Changes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Schema_changes/003n000000wn000000/)

If you're in a connected environment this is a much easier process. I was always disconnected form the other server, so it was a bit of a pain.

Comment: Hi ian. thanks a lot. We are using one-way replica. It should use the same way to manage right?

Comment: @ppLily yes, it will.